# Input encoding in RNNs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on developing a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) that performs the following task: there are 4 lights, and during each trial, one of them is turned on, followed by another one. The goal is to make a decision based on the combination of lights. Below is an example of a trial.

[image]

I'm wondering about encoding the input data for the RNN: Should I represent the first and second instances of a light turning on using the same 4 dimensions, or should I represent them separately, i.e. using 8 dimensions?

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Site says: "Ask about...

Specific programming problems,
Software algorithms,
Coding techniques,
Software development tools". This can fall under the next two.

Comment: Well, I guess so, but bear in mind that since the question is conceptual in nature, there are other forums more specifically focused on questions of that kind. You can try here and a few people will see it and know what's going on, or you could try somewhere else where it's likely there's a greater proportion of readers who are knowledgeable about that stuff. This is essentially the calculation you'll need to make for yourself.

Comment: This is not a programming problem, you are asking for ML concepts, better to ask in a site for ML.

Comment: This is not a ML concept, this is simply Coding techniques.